# Material UI: Wrapping Tab children in a div element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

is there a way to have a material ui tabs component's tab children wrapped in div's?

```
<Tabs
    value={value}
    indicatorColor="primary"
    textColor="primary"
    onChange={handleChange}
  >
  <div>
    <Tab label="x" />
 </div>
 <div>
    <Tab label="y" />
</div>
  </Tabs>
```

Currently I am getting an error that states "The value provided to the tabs component is invalid, None of the tabs' children match with x". removing the divs solves this problem but I need these tabs wrapped in a div so I can have a handle to drag the tab. Any advice is much appreciated as I haven't seen a way to do this so successfully so far.

Answer (score 1):

The `Tabs` component receives only `Tab` components as children. You can't wrap the Tab in a `div`. If want to `drag and drop` the Tab component you can define the property `draggable="true"` directly:

```
<Tabs
    value={value}
    indicatorColor="primary"
    textColor="primary"
    onChange={handleChange}
  >
    <Tab label="x" draggable="true"/>
    <Tab label="y" draggable="true"/>
  </Tabs>
```

Comment: Where is this documented?

Comment: I see you have another question related to this, I will answer that question with an example.

Comment: Yeah if there is solution for dragging and dropping tabs to change the order that would be using material ui that would be great

Comment: The Material UI tabs API doesn't have an option to drag and drop but you can develop this functionality using native javascript

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to override the tab component to accept a div wrapper of some kind, I need a drag handle for the library I am trying to use. I appreciate the native html 5 example but I am leaning against using it compared to the library that I am trying to use. https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd